# Android Studio Structural Search for all Toast statements in code

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, structural-search

How do I use Structural Search feature in Android Studio and search code lines similar to

```
    Toast.makeText(someContext, " some text "+someVariable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I tried the following but it does not match any toast statement

$Method$($Parameter$)

Where Method = Toast.makeText
and $parameter is .* and any number of occurances upto  4

Comment: So, the resulting regex is `Toast.make(.*)`? And what is wrong with it? [It should match your string](https://regex101.com/r/WoQShj/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, Find via regex does the thing - but I want to learn how "Structural Search" works. It does not match to the line.

Comment: Ok, so you do not need a regex. I retagged the question with the `structural-search` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can structural search for:

```
Toast.makeText($argument$)
```

with $argument$ min/max `0,4`, text/regexp empty (empty is equivalent to `.*`)

Or if you want to find any Toast method:

```
Toast.$method$($argument$)
```